# Is a monochromatic, or non-monochromatic light visible at greater distance?

Tags: visible-light

Just what the title states.

Assuming identical conditions, excellent visibility - 
If a  1W monochromatic light source, and a 1W non-monochromatic light source were viewed at a location in deep space, which of the two would be visible from a greater distance?

Comment: Are you asking about sensitivity or scattering?

Comment: Not sure I understand what is asked. Could you put it in a layman's terms please?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that all depends on the wavelength frequency of your monochromatic light source.

Obviously, the $1/r^2$ falloff of the intensity is the same for both cases. What is more important here is the sensitivity of the human eye to specific colors. As you can read [here](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/video/lumiere.php3), the human eye is most sensitive for light around 550nm, which is yellowish (makes sense, since the Sun is also yellow).

Somewhat simplified: your 1W panchromatic light source will have *less* energy in the neighbourhood of the 550nm wavelength, **if** the 1W monochromatic light source will be emitting closely to or on this specific wavelength.

Therefore:

- if the monochromatic light source is yellow, you will be able to see it further out than a panchromatic source.
- If the monochromatic one is deep red, the panchromatic source will win.

Answer (score 2):

**Monochromatic** simply in electromagnetic radiation means, staying at a *single* frequency...

Simple example: If your non-monochromatic light has some colors (say red) which have longer wavelength, and your monochromatic light is violet, then the non-monochromatic one would reach you at greater distances... But, you'd need highly sensitive detectors to search that tiny **1W** lights...

Ultimately, we could conclude that distance traveled by these EM waves depends only on their wavelength (their energy) and not their state (mono or non-mono)

Comment: To me it is not quite clear about what physical effects you are talking here, do you mean [refraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction) ? In addition, the propagation of light rays depends on how the are scattered, absorbed, and reflected by the medium. This is described by the radiative transfer equation ([RTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_transfer_equation#The_equation_of_radiative_transfer)). I was not the downvoter here ... ;-)

Comment: @Dilation: What you said was right. But, the OP has mentioned *identical conditions* to be assumed in deep space..  But with this availability (no obstacles, no medium, excellent visibility), we could consider only the energy... **to reach the observer**. And Thank you...